# Socket based chat program doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, windows, sockets, network-programming, livechat

I'm trying to create a chatroom based on sockets which works on windows.

I have a server script:

```
# chat_server.py

import sys
import socket
import select

HOST = ''
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096
PORT = 9009

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
    threads = []

    #add server socket object to the list of readable connections
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print("Chat server started on port " + str(PORT))

    while 1:
        # get the list sockets wich are ready to be read through select
        # 4th arg, tiome_out = 0 : poll and never block
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)

        for sock in ready_to_read:
            # a new connection request recieved
            if sock == server_socket:
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print("Cient (%s, %s) connected" % addr)

                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)


            # a message from a client, not a new connection
            else:
                # process data recieved from client,
                try:
                    #receiving data from the socket.
                    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        # there is something in the socket
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + ']' + data)
                    else:
                        # remove the socket that's broken
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                        # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)

                    # exception
                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()

# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
        # send the message only to peer
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection
                socket.close()
                # broken socket, remove it
                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)

if __name__ == "___main__":

    sys.exit(chat_server())

chat_server()
```

And a client script:

```
# chat_client.py

import sys
import socket
import select
from threading import Thread

def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3):
        print('Usage: python chat_client.py hostname port')
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    #connect to remote host
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
    except:
        print('Unable to connect')
        sys.exit()

    print('Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages')
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    sock_send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock_send.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock_send.bind((host, port))

    def send_msg(sock):
        while True:
            # user entered a message
            s.send(sys.stdin.buffer.readline())
            sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    def recv_msg(sock):
        while True:
            # incoming message from remote server, s
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                if not data :
                    print('\nDisconnected from chat server')
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    Thread(target=send_msg, args=(sock_send,)).start()
    Thread(target=recv_msg, args=(sock_send,)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

The program is executed with:

```
$ python chat_server.py

$ python chat_client.py localhost 9009
```

If I run the code I won't get any Error. When I run several clients at the same time they all connect to the server correctly, but one client doesn't get the text another client has written.

I think something is wrong with the server's broadcast function, but I'm not sure what it is.

I already searched for similar questions, but I didn't find anything useful for fixing this problem. Please Help!

Comment: Why do you combine TCP with UDP connections? You never send anything over UDP.

Comment: I guess that happend because I originally wanted to use   ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list, [], [])
but that doesnt work on windows, that's why I searched for an opportunity.  Afterwards I got cunfused. I'm not that good at programming :/

Comment: `select` should work with windows, too. First, get unconfused, then ask a clear question.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to mention that 'socket_list' was 'socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]' and that in connection with select doesn't work with windows if I got the note on this page right (https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html?highlight=select.select#select.select). It always caused an error